# Bounding the eigenvalues of $B A B^T$ with the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Given a Hermitian positive semi-definite $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and a rectangular $m \times n$ matrix $B$, is there anything that can be said about the eigenvalues of the matrix $B A B^T$?

It seems to me like one can regroup the product with a test vector $x$ to show that $(x^T B)A(B^T x)$ is at least the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ and at most the largest eigenvalue of $A$. However, this seems like it’s too easy of a solution...

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense. Also, what is PSD?

Comment: @AlexM. surely "positive semidefinite".

Comment: In your second paragraph, you forgot that $B^tx$ need not have the same norm as $x$. But of course you can make trivial observations along these lines, for example if $B^t x$, $\|x\|=1$, is an eigenvector of the min ev $\lambda$ of $A$, then the smallest ev of $BAB^t$ is $\ge \lambda\|B^tx\|^2$.

Comment: @AlexM. I fixed the title.  PSD means positive semi definite.

Comment: @JayStanley: *"Bounding the eigenvalues of $BAB^T$ with $A$"* does not seem fixed to me; it simply makes no sense in English.

Comment: Take $A=I$ and recall that any psd matrix can be written as $B^TB$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following paper studies relations between $\lambda(BAB^T)$ and $\lambda(A)$:

Li, Mathias (1999). [The Lidskii-Mirsky-Wielandt theorem – additive and multiplicative versions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002110050397). Numerische Mathematik. January 1999, Volume 81, Issue 3, pp 377–413.